# How to use hsqldb in oracle compatibility mode and hibernate to get the next value of a sequence

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hsqldb

I am using hsqldb in oracle compatibility mode as a test database for an application written for Oracle.  I am also using hibernate.

In versions 2.3.0 (the latest as of this writing) and 2.2.9 of hsqldb the line

```
return name.equals(rangeTable.getSchemaName().name)
```

in the resolvesSchemaName(String name) function of the org.hsqldb.RangeVariable.java file throws a NullPointerException whenever hibernate creates the sql

```
select <SEQUENCE_NAME>.nextval from dual
```

because rangeTable.getSchemaName() returns null.

I thought that since http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_compatibility_oracle says that "The DUAL table and the expressions, ROWNUM, CURRVAL, NEXTVAL are supported in ORA syntax mode" selecting nextval like hibernate is doing would work in hsqldb in oracle compatibility mode.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the dialect (hibernate.dialect) on my hibernate session factory from

```
org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

to

```
org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
```

which changed the SQL syntax hibernate generated to get the next value of the sequence and then there were no more NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: This is a bug and has been fixed for version 2.3.1.